# Creating search filter through plugin

Tags: plugins, php, filters, search

I'm using wordpress for real estate project, for that, I am using a theme together with a plugin (realia real estate) to real estate. So I believe that this not is beside the point ... My question is simple, I have several custom meta_key such as property_baths (bathrooms), property_beds (rooms) and etc ... What I want to do is create a filter, an advanced search in the wordpress management, in the "Posts" tab. I need also that this search be cumulative, for example, if the "bathrooms" and the "rooms" are both filled, should filter posts according to what has been filled.

After much searching I found a way to do this by creating a plugin, but the code that I have here, it is passing only only 1 meta_key with your meta_value, I need it to pass several meta_key with their values ...

What I have so far is this:

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );

function wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts(){
    $type = 'property';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }

    //only add filter to post type you want
    if ('property' == $type){
        //change this to the list of values you want to show
        //in 'label' => 'value' format
        $values = array(
            'Banheiros' => 'property_baths', 
            'Quartos' => 'property_beds'
        );

        $current_v = isset($_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE'])? $_GET['ADMIN_FILTER_FIELD_VALUE']:'';
        foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
            printf
            (
            '<input type="text" name="%s"%s placeholder="%s"></option>',
            $value, 
            $value == $current_v? ' value="'.$current_v.'"':'', 
            $label 
            );
        }
    }
}

add_filter('parse_query', 'wpse45436_posts_filter');

function wpse45436_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'property';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'property' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['property_baths']) && $_GET['property_baths'] != '') {

        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'property_baths';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['property_baths'];
    }
}
```

With this code (plugin) I can filter only 1 meta_key, I need to do in a way that I can use several "meta_keys" with their values.

I've tried loop, I tried array, but nothing worked. I hope someone can help me ... Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2):

You can add more than one filter call, so each of your custom `meta_key`'s can be handled in separate code and when executed will cumulatively adjust the query.

Perhaps look at the `pre_get_posts` filter rather than `parse_query` (although the solution I'm suggesting could possibly work in either case). `pre_get_posts` gives you access to the current query before it is executed by WordPress, and you will limit the posts that the query will fetch from the database.

I haven't tested this code: it's just an edit here against your code to show you how you could approach this (so please check the syntax for errors).

You'd end up with something like this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'wpse45436_property_baths_posts_filter');

function wpse45436_property_baths_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'property';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'property' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['property_baths']) && $_GET['property_baths'] != '') {

        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'property_baths';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['property_baths'];
    }
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'wpse45436_property_beds_posts_filter');

function wpse45436_property_beds_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'property';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'property' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['property_beds']) && $_GET['property_beds'] != '') {

        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'property_beds';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['property_beds'];
    }
}
```

Check the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for further details on the `pre_get_posts` filter